# How to label categories in time series data?

Tags: python

I have time series data where each point on the time series is also part of a category. There are 3 categories and usually several points after each other are in the same category. I’d like to be able to plot the time series, but change the colour of the line according to which category the observation is in.

I currently have a solution which has the time series and then coloured points for each observation, based on their category, but it looks quite cluttered.

I’ve also tried out splitting the categories into 3 datasets and plotting them seperately, but then the lines don’t connect when the category changes in the series

I’m using python at the minute, but as I have the data set I’m not limited to a python solution.

Data snapshot:

```
Date         Value      Group
2016-04-01   0.65       2 
2016-04-02   0.66       0 
2016-04-03   0.65       0 
2016-04-04   0.69       1
```

Comment: Which plotting library do you use? matplotlib? Also, could you please add an example of the data and your current code? How do you keep track of the category? What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @Valentino matplotlib at the minute, but open to other libraries. Added some data. The categories were assigned to each point. No problem with current code, but it colours the data points, but I'd like to colour the line according to the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want, I make use also of pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

df = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='\s+') #or however you build the dataframe with pandas

for i in range(len(df.index)):
    if df.loc[i,'Group'] == 0:
        col = 'g' #green
    elif df.loc[i,'Group'] == 1:
        col = 'r' #red
    elif df.loc[i,'Group'] == 2:
        col = 'c' #cyan
    subdf = df.loc[i:i+2] #selecting two points
    mpl.plot(subdf['Date'], subdf['Value'], 'o'+col) #plot bullet points
    mpl.plot(subdf['Date'], subdf['Value'], col) #plot connecting line

mpl.show()
```

And this is the result:

[image]

The idea is to loop over the series taking each pair and plot it twice, the former to plot the bullet points, the latter to plot the connecting segment. The color is selected from the group ([here](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/colors_api.html) the color list).
I added the bullet points to show the different color of the last point: it may belong to a different group. The color of the segment corresponds to the color associated to the group of the first point.